# 404 error when flagging a question as a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, exact-duplicates

I'm trying to flag [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125842/are-you-able-to-change-mayors-on-animal-crossing-new-leaf) as a duplicate, but a little red box pops up giving me a 404  error.

Is this a bug or am I not allowed to flag as duplicate (yet?)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187255/404-error-during-flagging-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[This Meta SE Bug Report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192003/179041) figured out it was an issue to do with privileges. The developers removed the option when the user doesn't meet the required privilege level:

> if a flag type requires commenting privileges (as off-topic flags do) and the user doesn't have them, that flag type will not come up.